# How do I write code for a specific matrix?

Tags: python

The input to my program is meant to be a single integer, representing the size of the matrix (for example, 5).

The output would then be a 5x5 matrix, where each row starts with an ascending value starting at `1`, and each item to the right is one more than on the left:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

How would I go about doing that in Python?

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: Yeah I tried I got the output in single line I dont know to print in next lines but now it's clear ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Pythonic way to do it:

```
sz = int(input("Size? "))
print("\n".join([" ".join([str(base + delta + 1) for delta in range(sz)]) for base in range(sz)]))
```

Sample runs are (for inputs of `4` and `5`):

```
Size? 4
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7

Size? 5
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

Of course, I wouldn't hand that in as classwork unless you can explain how it works :-)

In terms of how it works, it uses list comprehension (nested) to form each individual row from each item, and the matrix as a whole from the rows. It also uses `string.join()` to turn those lists into strings with a specific separator character.

The expression:

```
[str(base + delta + 1) for delta in range(sz)]
```

is a list comprehension that gives a list of the strings created from the integers formed by the sum of `base`, `delta` and `1`, where `delta` ranges from `0` to `sz - 1` inclusive (`base` comes from the outer comprehension below).

That's the inner comprehension which we than pass into `" ".join()`, and that joins up all the elements of the list into a single string where each element is separated by a space.

The outer comprehension:

```
[<joined-inner>) for base in range(sz)]
```

does a similar job, creating a list of joined rows, providing a different `base` for each row. We then pass that into `"\n".join()` which joins all the rows into a single string, and each row separated by a newline character.

---

For a more conventional (non-Pythonic) method, you can use:

```
sz = int(input("Size? "))
for base in range(sz):
    for delta in range(sz):
        print(base + delta + 1, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: I understand the non pythonic way but  I can't understand your pythonic way can u explain .join() means

Comment: Now i understood that comprehension concept 

Answer (score 0):

A very simple code, not the best but works for something simple that you want

```
x = int(input())

matrix = ""

for i in range(1, x+1):
  for j in range (i, x+i):
    matrix += f"{j} "
  matrix += "\n"

print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,5):
  for j in range(1,6):
    a.append(i+j);
  print(a)
  a=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```js
string = ""
for i in range (1,6):
    for j in range (i,i+5):
        string = string + str(j) + " "
    print(string)
    string = ""
```

Some Python compilers will output it all in one line. If that happens, replace `print(string)` with `print(string+"\n")`